# Character set in MySQL; Can't insert special characters, why?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, database

I can't insert special characters. Whenever I try to, all characters BEFORE the special character gets inserted, but after the special character nothing is inserted into the field.

```
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die('Error connecting to mysql');
mysql_select_db($dbname,$conn);
mysql_set_charset('utf-8', $conn);

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'") or die(mysql_error());
```

I have set the table to utf-8 collation, and all fields as well...

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: You'll have to provide examples of the code you use to do the insert, and the results you get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you set the necessary UTF-8 parameters in your PHP config? I used to begin my PHP files with that:

```
    ini_set("mbstring.internal_encoding","UTF-8");
    ini_set("mbstring.func_overload",7);
```

Answer (score -2):

I had same issue for saving special characters in mysql database so i changed Collation to utf8mb4_unicode_ci, it made the sql query run and complete data was inserted into database. But special characters not supported with UTF-8 are replaced by '?'. But I found it better till permanent fix atleast full data is inserted into database.